# get all sub categories without specify any category

Tags: categories

I have 2 levels of categories ( one sub-category only. No `sub-sub` category ). I need to get all sub categories without parent category. (I don't want to specify any parent category.)

Example:

```
p_cat1
   s_cat1
   s_cat2
p_cat4
p_cat3
   s_cat4
   s_cat5
   s_cat7
```

from here, I need

```
s_cat1
s_cat2
s_cat4
s_cat5
s_cat7
```

And, I need there to be a URL for each of those sub-categories. I want to give `<a>` for each subcategory.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_categories).

> Returns an array of category objects matching the query parameters.
>
> Arguments are pretty much the same as [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_list_categories) and can be passed as either array or in query syntax.

```
// Fetch parent categories
$parent_categories = get_categories( 'parent=0' );

foreach ( $parent_categories as $parent_category ) {
  // Fetch child categories
  $args = array(
    'parent' => $parent_category->term_id
  );

  $categories = get_categories( $args );

  foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    printf( '<div>%s</div>', $category->name );
  }
}
```

This is a very simple example of the code without extra parameters like `hide_empty`, `type` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The **get_categories** function of Wordpress returns all the categories, you can loop over the list of categories returned by get_categories and check for the `parent` property, if parent is '0' then its the parent category other wise it is the sub category.

```
function get_sub_categories() {
    $cats = get_categories();
    $subcats = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ($cat->parent != '0') {
            $subcats[] = $cat;
        }
    }
    return $subcats;
}
```

I don't know how you want with URL but you can try the following function which will only return Sub categories name hyper linked to their category URLs

```
function get_sub_categories() {
    $cats = get_categories();
    $subcats = array();
    foreach( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ($cat->parent != '0') {
            $subcats[] = '<a href="' . get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) .'">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
        }
    }
    return $subcats;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I need with url. I want to give <a> for each subcategories.

Comment: This would work, but it would also get any Category that is not top level, not just Level 2. I think that is what the OP specified (although the question isn't 100% clear - he may have mentioned Level 2 as that is all he has set up!).

Comment: David the above function will get any category that is *NOT* top level which means all sub categories.

Answer (score 0):

```
function kill_childcat_postlink($link) {
    $result = $link;
    $bloghome = get_bloginfo( 'home' );
    if (preg_match('%' . $bloghome . '/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/$%i', $link))
        $result = preg_replace('%' . $bloghome . '/(.*?)/.*?/(.*?)/$%i', $bloghome . '/$1/$2/', $link);     
    return $result;
}
add_filter('post_link','kill_childcat_postlink');
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code does?